# Derive Object Type from Format String

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to derive the intended object type from a .NET format string in C#?  For example:

```
//Input parameters
var formatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";  //or "£0.00" for example
var stringValue = "2014-04-01"; //or "37.34" for example

//Logic
object value = null;

if (IsADate(formatString)) {
    objectValue = DateTime.Parse(stringValue);

} else if (IsANumber(formatString)) {
    objectValue = double.Parse(stringValue);

} else //etc

//Result
var resultString = String.Format(value,formatString);
```

I could obviously write out the `IsADate()` and `IsANumber()` functions, but wondered whether there is anything in the Framework that covers this already?

Comment: Do you just want to parse the `stringValue` or do you really need a function that maps a `formatString` to a `Type`?

Answer (score 3):

[`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) will make you your `IsDate()` function and  [`Int32.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) will make you your `IsNumber()` function.

Finally you should have something like that :

```
DateTime dateTime ; 
int anInt;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(formatString, stringValue , out dateTime)) {
    objectValue = DateTime.Parse(stringValue);

} else if (Int32.TryParse(stringValue , out anInt)) {
    objectValue = double.Parse(stringValue);

} else //etc
```

Comment: TryParse already outputs the DateTime if it succeeds, no need to Parse it a second time. `objectValue = dateTime` should be sufficient.

Comment: What I don't understand about your answer: You are trying to convert `dd/MM/yyyy` into a `DateTime`? That won't work! You can not parse the format string. I guess what you want is `TryParseExact(formatString, inputValue, out dateTime)`, which uses the format string to parse the given input into an ouput. If that works, chances are the format string was for a `DateTime`/`int` etc. And why do you `double.Parse` if you check whether it is an `Int32`?

Comment: You should use DateTime.TryParseExact with the given formatString and stringValue and for ints your answer won't work.

Comment: @Dirk : Thanks for your corretion.

Comment: @Ksv3n How will `Int32.TryParse("d", out anInt);` ever return true? `d` is a valid numeric format string, but fails to be parsed as a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You could force .NET to try and parse your input given the format string where possible. If that succeeds, chances are good you got the right type:

```
var formatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";  //or "£0.00" for example
var stringValue = "2014-04-01"; //or "37.34" for example

//Logic
object value = null;
DateTime dtDummy;
int intDummy;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(formatString, stringValue, out dtDummy)) {
    value = dtDummy;

} 
else
...
```

For some types (numeric types, for example) there's no such method.

Comment: Numbers (int, double, etc.) don't have a static method accepting a format string for parsing.

Comment: True. Then it's not possible to do that for numeric types, really.